# Include TeX header in R package for RMarkdown documents

Tags: r, header, package, latex, r-markdown

I want to create an R package containing a latex header file which would then be available from an RMarkdown document to create a PDF with slides via TeX. When I include a reference to the latex file in the header of the RMarkdown document, I can create my slides. But I do not know how to package it. So my two related questions are:

1. How can I put a LaTeX-file in an R package so that it can be accessed later?
2. How can I include the LaTeX file in a new RMarkdown document to create slides after loading the package (like a template)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. Do something like

```
---
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    includes: 
      in_header: my_header.tex
---
```

and the `my_header.tex` may be any (la)tex code, including package load and variable settings.  You can also have `before_body:` and more.

If you just want packages loaded there is also a simpler way via yaml but I don't have that handy as I use the above mechanism more often.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question 2 partly, but in which folder of the R package, which I create, should I put my_header.tex? In man/R/inst ?

Comment: Adding an entire not-yet-on-system latex style file is not really an idiom for (r)markdown, but if you must I would put in the same directory as the .Rmd file.  The `inst/` path is known to R, you need to make it known the (la)tex engine you use.  Different things.

Comment: So when I compile a source package and load it afterwards with library(myTexTemplate), the .tex-file will be in the inst folder somewhere? I can't see such a folder in any other installed packages.