# Changing *Chapter X* name in bookdown PDF

Tags: latex, r-markdown, bookdown

Instead of *Chapter X* when creating a PDF from bookdown, I would like it to be "Módulo X" (in Spanish).

So I would like to know how to change chapter name using bookdown.

My YAML is:

```
--- 
title: "TITLE"
author: "Mario Modesto-Mata"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: pdf_document
description: This is a minimal example of using the bookdown package to write a book.
  The output format for this example is bookdown::gitbook.
documentclass: book
link-citations: yes
bibliography: book.bib
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
language:
  label:
    chapter_name: "Módulo"
---
```

I tried with the last three line codes, with no success. Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [bookdown documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/internationalization.html) we can learn two things:

- There is no `language.label.chapter_name` but `language.ui.chapter_name`.
- This setting is meant for HTML output. For PDF output one should configure LaTeX.

Configuring LaTeX is quite simple. You only need to add `lang: es` to your header.
However, this will use "Capítulo" instead of "Módulo". One can adjust this by redefining the LaTeX command `\chaptername`. BTW, at the moment you are not using `bookdown` but the standard `pdf_docuemnt` from `rmarkdown`. If you wont to use `bookdown` features, you should use `bookdown::pdf_book` or `bookdown::pdf_document2`.

Putting everything together:

```
--- 
title: "TITLE"
author: "Mario Modesto-Mata"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: bookdown::pdf_book
description: This is a minimal example of using the bookdown package to write a book.
  The output format for this example is bookdown::gitbook.
documentclass: book
lang: es
link-citations: yes
bibliography: book.bib
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
header-includes:
  - \AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Módulo}}
---
```

Result:

[image]

Note that `header-includes` is nice for simple stuff in single file documents like this minimal example. In most cases one is better off including a `tex` into the header via `output.<your-format>.includes.in_header`, c.f. [Include TeX header in R package for RMarkdown documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44941902/include-tex-header-in-r-package-for-rmarkdown-documents).

Comment: It partially worked. Although Chapter has been changed for Capítulo (in Spanish), it seems that Módulo is not well implemented.

Comment: @antecessor Works for me. see attached screen-shot. Did you include the `header-inlcudes: ...` in your YAML headers? Otherwise a [mcve] would be in order.

Comment: Yes, I copy/pasted your code and when converting to PDF it keeps saying Capítulo instead of Módulo...