# bookdown: Is there an option to change chapter_name for report?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

Is there an option to change the chapter label from **Chapter** to **Topic** in the report output `documentclass: report`? The above change did not result in the expected output.

[image]

Here are the index file and yml.

`index.Rmd`:

```
--- 
title: "Report"
author: "P"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: report
bibliography: [book.bib, packages.bib]
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
description: "This is a minimal example of using the bookdown package to write a book. The output format for this example is bookdown::gitbook."
header-includes:
  - \AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Topic}}
---
```

`_output.yml`:

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  css: style.css
  config:
    toc:
      before: |
        <li><a href="./">A Minimal Book Example</a></li>
      after: |
        <li><a href="https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown" target="blank">Published with bookdown</a></li>
    download: ["pdf", "epub"]
bookdown::pdf_book:
  includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
  latex_engine: xelatex
  citation_package: natbib
  keep_tex: yes
bookdown::epub_book: default
```

`_bookdown.yml`:

```
book_filename: "Report"
delete_merged_file: true
language:
  ui:
    chapter_name: 'Topic'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing \*Chapter X\* name in bookdown PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676107/changing-chapter-x-name-in-bookdown-pdf)

Comment: @RalfStubner Thanks for the link. I have made the changes, but it did not result in the expected output. Please check the updated content.

Comment: Did the `\renewcommand` make it to the resulting `tex` file? Did you try putting the command into `preamble.tex`?

Comment: @RalfStubner Nope, it did not make it to the `tex` file and the latter did not work as well.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with `header-includes` on a full `bookdown` project. Using `preamble.tex` does work for me, though, c.f. https://github.com/rstub/stackoverflow/blob/master/56430295/preamble.tex

Comment: Yes, it worked now on `site: bookdown::bookdown_site` and not on `output: bookdown::pdf_book`, though it should work for both.

Comment: @RalfStubner Please post this as an answer to this question, I would then accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194423/discussion-between-ralf-stubner-and-prradep).

Answer (score 1):

The chapter label from **Chapter** to **Topic** has been changed after making the following change in the `preamble.tex`.

Old file:

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
```

New file:

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Topic}}
```

Solution is given by: *Ralf Stubner*. Thank you Ralf!